# Sort email by the number of unread messages in Gmail web

Tags: gmail, sorting

I would like to sort the email senders by the number of unread messages.

In the web version of Gmail, they don't support this feature as far as I know.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your best bet will probably be finding a mail client that runs on your computer which has this capability. I would look at whether Thunderbird (or Thunderbird and an additional extension/add-on) can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is such a feature.
The best alternative would be writing a code by yourself using Selenium library.